# Progress of the Kazdan-Warner Problem on Higher-genus Surfaces

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry

I would like to understand if there is any further progress of the problem of prescribing Gaussian curvature on (oriented) closed surface $M$ with $\chi(M)<0$ in a conformal class after Kazdan and Warner.

To be more specific, given a metric $g_0$ on $M$ with the Gaussian curvature $K_{g_0}=-1$ and a smooth function $f$ on $M,$  there is a conformal metric $g$ of $g_0$ with the Gaussian curvature $f$ if and only if the following PDE admits a solution:
$$-fe^{2u}=\Delta_{g_0}u + 1.$$
Kazdan and Warner posted a series of articles discussing this problems in 60s. However, in such a case when $\chi(M)<0,$ I cannot find other general existence results after their study. The most famous parts of their conclusions are the following:

1. If $f$ is non-positive, then the PDE is solvable, using the method of subsolutions and supersolutions.
2. If the PDE is solvable, then $f$ can be written as $\frac 12 \Delta v - v$ for some smooth function $v,$ using the maximum principle.

I would, in particular, like to know whether there is any result concerning the sufficiency of the necessary conditions above. However, any relevant information is appreciated!